# Attempted to read write protected memory

Tags: c#, c++, memory, unmanaged

I have a C++ DLL that exports a method like this:

```
extern "C" __declspec (dllexport) void ConvE(int type, const char* path, int b1, int b2, int b3, int b4, int b5)
{
    FFileList file_list;

    char temp_path[1024];

    if(type == 1) 
    {
        sprintf(temp_path,"%s*",path);
        GetFindFileListWin(temp_path,".mrs",file_list);
        file_list.RecoveryZipE(b1, b2, b3, b4, b5);
        file_list.ConvertNameMRes2Zip();
    }
    else if(type == 2) 
    {
        sprintf(temp_path,"%s*",path);
        GetFindFileListWin(temp_path,".zip",file_list);
        file_list.ConvertZipE(b5, b4, b3, b2, b1);
        file_list.ConvertNameZip2MRes();
    }
}
```

And I'm calling it into my C# application like this:

```
[DllImport("Mrs.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Ansi, CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
public static extern void ConvE(int type, string path, int b1, int b2, int b3, int b4, int b5);
```

But everytime I run it, It throws me the error ***"Attempt to read or write Protected Memory This is often an indicating that other memory is corrupt"***

As far as I read, there's something wrong with the way I'm importing the function in C#, but I really don't know how to solve it.

Edit:
by default, there was a Conv() that is the same as my ConvE but without the 5 integers, and that one works fine.
I made ConvE to use file_list.RecoveryZipE() that previously when debugging, it stacks me on a method inside that one called RecvoeryCharE (I added it to my code, you can take a look to it) and also, that one was base on RecoveryChar() that works on Conv().

***RecoveryChar:***

```
void RecoveryChar(char* pData,int _size)
{
    if(!pData) return;
    BYTE b,bh,d;

    for(int i=0;i<_size;i++) {
        b = *pData;
        bh = b&0x07;
        d = (bh<<5)|(b>>3);
        *pData = d ^ 0xff;
        pData++;
    }
}
```

***RecvoeryCharE:***

```
void RecoveryCharE(char* pData, int _size, int b1, int b2, int b3, int b4, int b5)
{
    if(!pData) return;

    BYTE b;

    for(int i=0;i<_size;i++) {
        b = *pData;
        b = (((((b >> b1) | (b << 5)) ^ b2) + b3) ^ b4) - b5;
        *pData = b;
        pData++;
    }
}
```

**Last Exception I got when debugging the C# app:**
[image: Exception]

Edit: After debugging it again, it stucks on here

```
RecoveryCharE( _fileheaderReader , _fileheaderReaderSize, b1, b2, b3, b4, b5 );
```

For some reason, **b1** value is taking 0 always.
[image: Inserted values]
and seems that for that reason I'm getting the protected memory error.

All I did was copy all the methods where recoveryChar() and convertChar() were present and pass the values as parameters.

Comment: If you change the function body to be empty, does the error still occur? If yes - there's something wrong inside the function. If not - there's something wrong with you importing it.

Comment: This error usually occurs when you're trying to access a non-existing index in an array, maybe your file list is empty or you asked for the 4th file in a list of only 2 files

Comment: @EduardoWada I updated my question with more information related to my error, please take a look and thanks for reply.

Comment: This exception only says it happened in the C++ code, you'll have to debug the C++ DLL to find the line where it happens and the variable's values when it happens.

Comment: @EduardoWada
I upload the results of the debug. Thanks again for trying to help me. Should I post the original codes and my edits?

Comment: Not really sure if that can be the problem but `ConvE` receives a `const char *` and `RecoveryCharE` receives a `char *` and tries to changes it. Are you passing the string received by `ConvE` to `RecoveryCharE`? If that is so, probably the C# VM isn't happy about you changing a string inside it.

Answer (score 0):

I would explore those things:

1. What are your platform on C++ and on C# side ? Are they both 32-bits ? both 64-bits ? You may have an issue with your parameters transfer between the two languages done wrong if you have a mix of integer length. Anyway the safest bet would be to specify the exact integer width using for instance 'int32_t' instead of just 'int'
2. Some people suggest specifiying the exact marshaller when converting c++ 'char*' to c# 'string' using for instance "MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPStr)] string path", please try this
3. Finally add some "printf-like" debugging code in your C++ to dump all the values at various steps (including just at the begining of the call) to the debugging console. You can use the following function which is used just like printf but outputs to the debuging console.

Code sample for debug output in C++:

```
inline void log_(const char *format, ...)
{
  va_list args;
  va_start(args, format);

  char buffer[1000];
  vsprintf(buffer, format, args);
  OutputDebugStringA(buffer);
}
```